# Grouped Table view in Iphone with one section

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hello
I am using grouped tableview to fill entries in text fields. I m using one section and 9 rows.
and place one label and text field with place holder. it is  repeating rows and when I start editing text field it does not clear place holder it is overriding.And i used switch also when i scroll first row automatically display switch which i used in last row.whats wrong with my code???
here is my code...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 9;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



        if (indexPath.row==0)
        {


        UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
        [Name setText:@"First Name "];
        [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

        UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
        //textName.placeholder=@"Enter First Name";
        [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
        textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
        textName.delegate=self;
        textName.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


        }



        if (indexPath.row==1)
        {

            UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 110, 20)];
            [Name setText:@"Middle Name"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

            UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            textName.placeholder=@"Enter Middle Name";
            [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            textName.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


        }

        if (indexPath.row==2)
        {
            UILabel *Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
            [Name setText:@"Last Name "];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

            UITextField *textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            textName.placeholder=@"Enter Last Name";
            [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            textName.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];


        }



        if (indexPath.row==3) {


            UILabel *Payment=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 20)];
            [Payment setText:@"Credit Card"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Payment];


            paymentText=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            paymentText.placeholder=@"Payment Type";
            [paymentText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            paymentText.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            paymentText.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
            //paymentText.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            //paymentText.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            //paymentText.delegate=self;


            picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            const int kPaymentPickerTag = 3002;
            //picker.hidden=NO;
            picker.tag = kPaymentPickerTag;
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.dataSource = self;

            [picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];


            //display picker on textfield payment

            //paymentText.inputView = picker;
            paymentText.inputView=picker;

        //  paymentText.inputAccessoryView=picker;




            //[cell.contentView addSubview:PaymentPicker];


            [cell.contentView addSubview:paymentText];
        }

        if (indexPath.row==4) {


            UILabel *Card=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 20)];
            [Card setText:@"Card Number"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Card];


            UITextField *CardText=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            CardText.placeholder=@"Enter Card Number";
            [CardText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            CardText.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            CardText.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            CardText.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            CardText.delegate=self;
            CardText.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:CardText];
        }
        if (indexPath.row==5) {


            UILabel *date=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 20)];
            [date setText:@"Exp Date"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:date];


            DateText=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            DateText.placeholder=@"Select Date";
            [DateText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            DateText.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            DateText.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;

            UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
            [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(DateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

            NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            dateComponents.year = 1980;
            dateComponents.month = 1;
            dateComponents.day = 1;
            NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
            datePicker.date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
            [dateComponents release];
            [gregorian release];

            //date picker on textfield
            DateText.inputView = datePicker;
            [datePicker release];


            [cell.contentView addSubview:DateText];
        }
        if (indexPath.row==6) {


            UILabel *Amt=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 20)];
            [Amt setText:@"Amount"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Amt];

            UITextField *AmtText=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            AmtText.placeholder=@"Enter Amount";
            [AmtText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            AmtText.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            AmtText.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
            AmtText.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            AmtText.delegate=self;
            AmtText.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:AmtText];
        }
        if (indexPath.row==7) {


            UILabel *address=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 20)];
            [address setText:@"Billing Address"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:address];


            UITextField *addressText=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
            addressText.placeholder=@"Enter Address";
            [addressText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            addressText.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            addressText.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
            addressText.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            addressText.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:addressText];
            addressText.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
            /*UIButton* pencil = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [pencil setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            pencil.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
            pencil.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [pencil addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapEditButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            cell.accessoryView = pencil     ;
             */
          cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        }
        if (indexPath.row==8) {

            UILabel *Gift=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 20)];
            [Gift setText:@"Gift Receipt"];
            [cell.contentView  addSubview:Gift];


            GiftText=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 180, 20)];

            GiftText.text=@"Yes";
            [GiftText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
            GiftText.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
            GiftText.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            GiftText.delegate=self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:GiftText];

            switchView=[[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 5, 30, 10)];

            switchView=[UISwitch switchWithLeftText:@"Yes" andRight:@"No"];
            switchView.on=YES;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:switchView];


            cell.accessoryView=switchView;

            [(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        }






    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     UILabel *Name;
     UITextField *textName;

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    Name=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 20)];
    Name.tag =1001;
    [Name setText:@"First Name "];
    [cell.contentView  addSubview:Name];

    textName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 150, 20)];
    //textName.placeholder=@"Enter First Name";
    textName.tag =1002
    [textName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
    textName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    textName.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    textName.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
    textName.delegate=self;
    textName.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textName];

    }else{
    Name = (UILable*)[cell.contentview viewwithtag:1001];
     textName = (UItextField*)[cell.contentview viewwithtag:1002];
    }

    if(indexpath.row==0){
     Name=@"aaa";
     textName =@"bbb";
    }...
    .
    .
    .
```